# Reduce Queries in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to retrieve a list of collections ie @medications, @treatments, @therapies etc. with a count of each collections related records.

This works but creates the initial query and then a new query for each related record count.  Is there a way I can minimize the number of queries?

```
@medications = Medication.includes(:records).select(:id, :name).where(office_id: current_user.selected_office)

@medications.each do |medication|
  medication.record_count = medication.records.count
end
```

if @medications query has 10 results I have total of 11 queries. I need 10 collections with related record counts so I would end up with 110 queries per request.

All models have same attributes of name, office_id , etc

I am wondering how I can restructure database to better use or restructure query.  Incidentally I am using Postgres db v 9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about with joins and count?:

```
Medication.left_outer_joins(:records)
          .select('medications.name, medications.id, COUNT(records.id) AS records_count')
          .group(:id)
          .where(office_id: current_user.selected_office)
```

If you're planning to count on each record per medication, then you can use `joins`, and `count` passing the records and assigning an alias.

As each model has the name and id columns, you need to be more precise on defining them, and group in this case (correct me if I'm wrong), is mandatory, otherwise you'd get a `PG::GroupingError`.

Comment: for some reason that was not returning any results. you got me thinking and I decided to use Medication.left_outer_joins(:records) which go me what I needed.  If you want to edit your answer I'll accept.    Thanks

Comment: Oops, I tried to replicate your models and their relationships. Maybe I wasn't that accurate.

Comment: no- your good.  I think the issue was that my medication does not have records but records has medication